# Need help creating dynamic parameter options for Joomla module

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla-module

I am working on a Joomla module to allow pulling named content snippets from an external website. The best way to do that would be to add either a [List parameter](http://docs.joomla.org/List_parameter_type) to the manifest, or a [SQL parameter](http://docs.joomla.org/Sql_parameter_type) to the manifest, but both options have some critical flaw which makes them unusable to me in their current state. The list parameter has to be supplied with options before install, which will not work because the content it can pull may change from moment to moment. The SQL parameter type seemed like a better option at first, but it can only pull from the Joomla database for the current installation. The data I need to pull may very well be on a different server. I am at a loss... anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create your own custom parameter type to use in the manifest file.
Have a look at a example of "custom parameter" http://docs.joomla.org/SQLMultiSelectX and when creating your own one use standard PHP functions to connect with your SQL database.

Comment: I think that's the solution I'm going to need. Thanks!